# check for duplicates in sql

Tags: sql, join, group-by, duplicates, teradata

I am joining two tables A and B. My query looks something like this.

```
select id, name, sum(qty) 
from table 1 
left join table 2 on table1.id = table2.id and table2.column = XXXX
group by 1,2
```

I want to know if this join is creating any duplicated rows in table 1.

Im using teradata SQL

Comment: Hello jahan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your query is not valid SQL. Please provide sample data and desired results (as tabular text), so one can try and sort this out. You should also tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: first of all what RDBMS are you using? Also the term duplicate if a very vague term, what is considered a duplicate in your result set? 2 identical names? 2 identical IDs or 2 identical set of Id and Name ?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, im using teradata sql. only id is identical, nothing else. Basically what im looking for is, how to write the query to check if the join on table 2 is creating duplicate rows in table 1 on the only identical coloumn ID.

Comment: @GMB, I know i missed group by 1,2 and i dont see a edit option to edit the query :)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/625760)

Comment: @jahan: not only that. `XXXX` should be enclosed with single quotes. Column `id` in the select clause is ambiguous, because it is not qualified with a table name or alias, and it exists in both tables. `table 1` is not valid (it is unquoted, and contains a space). As for editing, there is an [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61705435/edit) right under the question.

Comment: I do not understand your question/problem. First, this is a select query, it won't modify any of the content of the tables. Second, it is an aggregation query grouped by `id, name`, therefore, the result set generated will only consist of unique (distinct) combinations of those two columns (i.e. `id` and `name`). If there were multiple records consisting of a single `id,name` value, they will be collapsed into a single record with the `qty` value being summed up to a single value based upon all of those "multiple records" for each `id, name` combination.

Comment: Also, on Teradata, unless your table is defined as "MULTISET", the default will be "SET". In a nutshell, "SET" means that if duplicate rows are selected for insert, they will either: a) be collapsed into a single record prior to being inserted or b) result in a duplicate row or duplicate unique index error. The actual result will depend upon the query used to insert into the table and the table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to know if more than one row may exist in `table2` that matches your join conditions. Here is a query for that purpose:

```
select t2.id
from table2 t2
where 
    t2.colum = 'XXXX'
    and exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
group by t2.id
having count(*) > 1
```

Any row returned by that query would duplicate the rows in your existing join.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is perhaps something along the lines of

```
select id, name, sum(qty) 
from table 1 as t1
left join table 2 as t2 on table1.id = table2.id and table2.column = XXXX
where t1.id in (select distinct id from table 1 )
```

Distinct checks for row distinction and you mentioned the only column where you need to check for duplicates is ID.